# glibc #define PTR_MANGLE(var) syntax

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, glibc, libc

I'm [reading through](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/PointerEncryption) how pointer guard works, and looking at the glibc macro [that does it](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h.html#_M/PTR_MANGLE):

```
#  define PTR_MANGLE(var)        asm ("xor %%fs:%c2, %0\n"                      \
                                     "rol $2*" LP_SIZE "+1, %0"                      \
                                     : "=r" (var)                              \
                                     : "0" (var),                              \
                                       "i" (offsetof (tcbhead_t,              \
#  define PTR_DEMANGLE(var)        asm ("ror $2*" LP_SIZE "+1, %0\n"              \
                                     "xor %%fs:%c2, %0"                              \
                                     : "=r" (var)                              \
                                     : "0" (var),                              \
                                       "i" (offsetof (tcbhead_t,              \
                                                      pointer_guard)))
```

The syntax is a little cryptic so I'm having a hard time understanding how `PTR_DEMANGLE` eventually produces assembly code like this:

```
ror    rdx,0x11
xor    rdx,QWORD PTR fs:0x30
call   rdx
```

How is string substitution working here?
What is the meaning of `:` in this context? (I don't see a conditional assignment?)

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Comment: "The syntax is a little cryptic".  That's an understatement.

Comment: `fs` is an x86 _segment_ register. Under linux, `fs` is used as the base address of the "thread local storage" area. Application variables defined with `__thread` go in this area. The contents of `fs` is _different_ for each thread in a process, thus any variable defined this way will have a [possibly] different/independent value for each thread. On other arches, usually a given register is designated as the TLS base register. Because x86 has so few, `fs` was co-opted for this purpose. This is a way to prevent/reduce inter-thread demangle of another thread's encrypted pointer

Comment: Indeed, there's quite a lot going on with these few lines of code.  Explaining everything from start to finish, from macro expansion to assembly output, would require a very long answer.  Maybe you can be a bit more specific about what stages you do and don't understand?  In particular, I am not sure exactly what you mean by "string substitution".

Comment: A couple hints, though: the `:` symbols are part of the gcc extended inline assembly syntax (see the link posted above by HolyBlackCat), and they have nothing to do with the `?:` ternary operator.  Also, this asm statement is using AT&T assembly syntax, whereas your disassembly is in Intel syntax, which may be part of what is confusing you.  The assembly it generates will actually look like `ror $2*8+1, %rdx ; xor %fs:0x30, %rdx`.  The `call` is not produced by this macro and presumably comes from code that follows the macro invocation.

Comment: Thanks all! I was not familiar with Extended Asm, and that fills the gap for me. Should I write an answer to this breaking down the syntax or are the comments here enough for future readers?