# What does fs:0x30 provide in Linux?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, glibc, thread-local-storage

I am trying to understand the source code of [atexit()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) function,but I stuck on [this](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h.html#410)
(line 409 ~ line 415, **PTR_DEMANGLE()**)

I can understand the inline asm need do a vital progress

```
xor    rdx,QWORD PTR fs:0x30
```

But I didn't really get what's fs:0x30 meaning for

So I searched for google but only got the meaning of fs:0x30 on Windows ,which is reletive to PEB

And I also tried search for **PTR_DEMANGLE()** function directly,and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766739/glibc-define-ptr-manglevar-syntax),but it didn't help

And this also raise me a new question:

Say,I need to know usage of fs:0xXX,that is few-used. which manual-book should I refer to ,directly? ELF standard document?

BTW,English is not my first language,this post may have some syntax or spelling mistakes,please forgive me,thx very much!

Comment: Btw, I removed the [tag:linux-kernel] tag because this code is not part of the kernel.  (In fact the kernel uses fs / gs in quite different ways than userspace.)

Comment: fs:0x30 is right next to the standard fs:0x28 stack cookie used for `-fstack-protector-strong` that most distros enable by default in their GCC config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `fs` segment register is used in x86-64 Linux to point to thread-local storage.  See [How are the fs/gs registers used in Linux AMD64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611346/how-are-the-fs-gs-registers-used-in-linux-amd64?noredirect=1&lq=1) So this instruction will xor the `rdx` register with the value found at offset 0x30 in the thread-local storage block.

This code is part of a pointer encryption mechanism in glibc to help harden against certain exploits.  There is some explanation of it at https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/PointerEncryption.  The value at `fs:0x30` is an "key" for a trivial "encryption" algorithm; pointers are xor'ed with this value (and then rotated) when they are stored, and rotated back and xor'ed again when they are retrieved from memory, which recovers the original pointer.

There is no particular significance to the number 0x30; it just happens to be the offset where that value is stored.  You can see in the inline assembly that this number comes from `offsetof (tcbhead_t, pointer_guard)`; so the storage at the `fs` base address is laid out as a `tcbhead_t` struct, and given the other members that it contains, the `pointer_guard` member has ended up at offset `0x30`.  So looking at the name `pointer_guard` for the member is more informative than its numerical offset.

Comment: *There is no particular significance to the number 0x30* That's really helpful,thx!!